# Ubuntu 16.07 php7.0 and xdebug

Tags: php, apache2, xdebug, php-7, ubuntu-16.04

Recently I have learned how too use xdebug and I want to try and install it to the php.ini for apache.

I managed to install php7.0 as apache module and NOT to run it via php-fpm.

As I have seen the following configuration works for php 5.x versions:

```
[PHP]
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20131226/mailparse.so
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20131226/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp 
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.max_nesting_level=300
```

But it may need some tweak to work for php 7.0 . Do you know how to tweak it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end my configuration on file `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` is:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.max_nesting_level=300
```

And worked like a charm.